# Allow using fullscreen API automatically or simulating keypresses in own browser build

Tags: javascript, browser, fullscreen

I try to make my website load in fullscreen automatically, without user input. However, this does not seem to be possible with the fullscreen API via Javascript. Simulating a keypress (F11) is also not allowed because of security reasons.

I've read in another question, that I could fork an existing browser and therefore allow using the fullscreen API automatically (and possibly simulating keypresses as well..?).

Since I only need this for a private project on my own machine this sounds feasible to me, but I don't have a clue where to start. I've tried looking in the Chromium Sourcecode for their implementation of the fullscreen API, to no real success.

So: Is what I described possible to achieve with browser-side modifications? Where can I start looking (or find out what to look for) in let's say Chromium (or whatever open source browser)? Is this likely to be accomplished without years of experience in browser technologies? Or are there other more suitable places where I can ask? Thanks alot

/edit
To clarify, just starting the website/browser in fullscreen mode (if even possible reliably) probably won't fix my problem either, because I need to switch to non-fullscreen sometimes as well.

Comment: Looks like kiosk-mode could solve your problems. In kiosk-mode, normal security-features can be relaxed, for example allowing fullscreen and audio without user intervention.

Comment: If you want to use Chrome on windows, you can read more at [running-latest-chrome-for-windows-in-kiosk-mode](https://superuser.com/questions/716426/running-latest-chrome-for-windows-in-kiosk-mode) or search for kiosk mode for your desired browser and operating system.

Comment: Thanks, sadly this does not work for me because I need to be able to switch between fullscreen/normal as well, which does not work in kiosk mode (I don't know if your answer was before or after my edit)

Comment: You should put your explanation that you put in justpaste in your question. Since you don't want to use a wireless keyboard, or any other remote desktop apps, I can't help you and will delete my answer.